# How do I add a line in a cell if it meets certain condition?

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code that adds a line in front/mid/end if it first does not exist in the cell.

The cell has the original text:

```
T - xxxxx
O - xxxxx
P - xxxxx
```

In some cells, it does not have T/O/P and thus I am required to write:

```
T - xxxxx
O - None
P - None
```

Is there a way to check if it doesn't have the statement first then add the line in front/middle/end?

```
For i = 5 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

If InStr(Cells(i, "F").Value, "T -") Then
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F").Value
Else
    Cells(i, "F").Value = "T - None" & vbCrLf & Cells(i, "F")
End If

If InStr(Cells(i, "F").Value, "O -") Then
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F").Value
Else
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F") & vbCrLf & "O - None"
End If

If InStr(Cells(i, "F").Value, "P -") Then
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F").Value
Else
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F") & vbCrLf & "P - None"
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Not sure what InStr does though.

Answer (score 0):

`InStr` function finds the position of a specified substring within the string and returns the first position of its occurrence. If an occurrence of the given string is not found then it returns zero. So if we want to check if `String2` is inside `String1` we need to evaluate `InStr(String1, String2) > 0`

For your solution, we can create one list with all the required components, iterate through all the components and check if they are present in the text and if not add a default value for that. So the solution will look something like this.

```
Sub test()

Dim text As String
text = "T - xxxxx" & vbNewLine & "O - xxxxx"
Dim Components(3) As String
Components(0) = "T -"
Components(1) = "O -"
Components(2) = "P -"

text = WorksheetFunction.Trim(text)
For Each comp In Components
    If InStr(text, comp) <= 0 Then 'If component is not present
        text = text & vbNewLine & comp & " None"
    End If
Next

Debug.Print text
'prints
'T - xxxxx
'O - xxxxx
'P - None
End Sub
```